# Why does No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' browser error have a status code?

Tags: javascript, php, security, cross-browser, accesscontrolexception

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load <website>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '<otherwebsite>' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.`

What I'm curious about is that last line at the end. There's some point in my php code that I can change the status code and it changes the number in that output. But if the browser is blocking the request, how is it possible that server side application code where this change is happening is being executed?

Comment: How is what possible? Question is not very clear

Comment: The browser can receive the http status code, in this case a "401 not authorized", but the same-origin policy disallows the page from loading after the status code and other headers are received, as it needs to read the headers to check for a CORS header anyway

Comment: @charlietfl edited for more clarity.

Comment: @adeneo thanks for your response. how can it be processing the request server side when this is what the same origin policy is attempting to disallow? The 401 is explicitly set in server side app code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control

Comment: doing a cross-domain ajax call means your browser hits the specified site with an `OPTIONS` request, so it can check that access-control header is present, and allows the request. that OPTIONS call ended up getting a 401 error.

Comment: thanks @MarcB. Does that mean that  controller code may be executed during an OPTIONS request?

Comment: CORS is enforced by the client after the response is received, so that means the controller code will have run already.

Comment: If you want the controller code to run on the server, just use the example here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control Check to see if your origin is as expected.  If it was, then advise your receiving browser that the communication is valid by setting the header for header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ...)  That CORS is there to cut down on cross site.  That's why there are verification examples, etc.